# Error: Matrix dimensions must agree for plot

Tags: matlab, debugging, matrix, plot, dimensions

having a problem with my "new love", matlab: I wrote a function to calculate an integral using the trapz-method: `

```
function [L]=bogenlaenge_innen(schwingungen)
R = 1500;            %Ablegeradius
OA = 1;              %Amplitude
S = schwingungen;    %Schwingungszahl
B = 3.175;           %Tapebreite

phi = 0:2.*pi./10000:2.*pi;

BL = sqrt((R-B).^2+2.*(R-B).*OA.*sin(S.*phi)+OA.^2.*(sin(S.*phi)).^2+OA.^2.*S.^2.*(cos(S.*phi)).^2);   

L = trapz(phi,BL)`
```

this works fine when i start it with one specific number out of the command-window. Now I want to plot the values of "L" for several S.

I did the following in a new *.m-file:
 `W = (0:1:1500);
T = bogenlaenge_innen(W);
plot(W,T)`

And there it is:

> Error using  .* 
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.

What is wrong? Is it just a dot somewhere? I am using matlab for the second day now, so please be patient.... ;) Thank you so much in advance!

PS: just ignore the german part of the code, it does not really matter :)

Comment: You should have a look at the size of T

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely because you have made it so that the number of elements in `schwingungen`, i.e. `W` in your code, must be equal to the number of elements in `phi`. Since `size(W)` gives you a different result from `size(0:2.*pi./10000:2.*pi)`, you get the error.

The way `.*` works is that is multiplies each corresponding elements of two matrices provided that they either have the same dimensions or that one of them is a scalar. So your code will work when `schwingungen` is a scalar, but not when it's a vector as chances are it has a different number of elements from the way you hard coded `phi`.

The simplest course of action (not necessarily the most Matlabesque though) for you is to loop through the different values of `S`:

```
W = (0:1:1500);
T = zeros(size(W); %Preallocate for speed)

for ii = 1:length(W)
    T(ii) = bogenlaenge_innen(W(ii));
end

plot(W,T)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the arrays `S` and `phi` in the expression `sin(S.*phi)` should have same size or one of them should be a constant in order the code works

Answer (score 0):

In your function you define phi as a vector of 10001 elements.
In this same function you do S.*phi,  so if S is not the same length as phi, you will get the "dimensions must agree" error.
In your call to the function you are doing it with a vector of length 1501, so there is your error.

Regards